# AS3 + webcam. Dispatch event on presence

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, webcam, code-snippets, motion

I would like to know if anyone has a snippet I can adapt to achieve the following:

I've got a flash projector with some sounds embed, that needs to be lunched when the PS EYE camera I've got attached detects a motion in the room.

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Your question is off topic for StackOverflow.  see the help for information about how to ask a good question here.    I can tell you that it's certainly possible ,  Flash even has a built in activity method on the `Camera` class that makes it fairly easy.      http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/22/detecting-changes-in-a-cameras-activity-and-status-in-a-flex-videodisplay-control/

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ActivityEvent.html

Comment: projector are so limited in functionality that it'll be very difficult at best or more likely impossible to achieve. Make it an AIR app.

Comment: @Batman thanks for the links, Im checking them, also sorry about the off topic-ness in case I did.
-BotMaster yes I did figure that sadly, thanks

Comment: You can easily make your question on topic by editing it to show what you've tried, and asking for help/example instead of off-site resources or asking for a complete solution without showing you've tried anything first - also, I think projectors can use the `Camera` class, which is the only real dependency here - though I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to just use AIR.